# How to build android standalone toolchain in windows 7

Tags: android, windows-7, toolchain

I am trying to build standalone toolchain using ndk 8 for mips by following "docs\STANDALONE-TOOLCHAIN.html" but when I run following command "make-standalone-toolchain.sh --platform=android-14 --install-dir=/tmp/my-android-toolchain" in command prompt I got following errors

```
E:\Installed_SDKs\android-ndk-r8\build\tools>make-standalone-toolchain.sh --plat
form=android-14 --arch=mips --install-dir=./mytool
Welcome to Git (version 1.7.9-preview20120201)


Run 'git help git' to display the help index.
Run 'git help <command>' to display help for specific commands.
expr: syntax error
expr: syntax error
./prebuilt-common.sh: line 159: name: No such file or directory
./prebuilt-common.sh: line 159: OPTIONS_abstract_Specify: command not found
expr: syntax error
expr: syntax error
./prebuilt-common.sh: line 159: name: No such file or directory
./prebuilt-common.sh: line 159: OPTIONS_abstract_Specify: command not found
expr: syntax error
expr: syntax error
./prebuilt-common.sh: line 159: path: No such file or directory
./prebuilt-common.sh: line 159: path: No such file or directory
./prebuilt-common.sh: line 159: OPTIONS_default_.=: command not found
expr: syntax error
expr: syntax error
./prebuilt-common.sh: line 159: name: No such file or directory
./prebuilt-common.sh: line 159: OPTIONS_abstract_Specify: command not found
expr: syntax error
expr: syntax error
./prebuilt-common.sh: line 159: path: No such file or directory
./prebuilt-common.sh: line 159: path: No such file or directory
./prebuilt-common.sh: line 159: OPTIONS_default_/tmp/ndk-=: No such file or directory
expr: syntax error
expr: syntax error
./prebuilt-common.sh: line 159: path: No such file or directory
./prebuilt-common.sh: eval: line 159: unexpected EOF while looking for matching
`''
./prebuilt-common.sh: eval: line 160: syntax error: unexpected end of file
expr: syntax error
expr: syntax error
./prebuilt-common.sh: line 159: name: No such file or directory
./prebuilt-common.sh: line 159: OPTIONS_abstract_Specify: command not found
./prebuilt-common.sh: line 159: OPTIONS_default_android-3=: command not found
expr: syntax error
expr: syntax error
expr: syntax error
expr: syntax error
expr: syntax error
ERROR: Unknown option '--platform=android-14'. Use --help for list of valid values.
```

Can any body guide what I am doing wrong! or how could I build standalone toolchain in windows 7

Regards
Ahsan

Comment: Did you ever figure this out (as nobody submitted any answers)?

Answer (score 4):

```
$ E:>Installed_SDKs/android-ndk-r9d/build/tools/make-standalone-toolchain.sh --platform=android-14 --arch=mips --system=windows-x86_64
```

generates `/tmp/ndk-/mipsel-linux-android-4.6.tar.bz2` for me; now I can unpack this file to `E:\Installed_SDKs\android-ndk-r8\build\tools\mytool` and live happily ever after.

Comment: For anyone using a newer version of the NDK, you have to replace --system=windoes-x86_64 by --system=windows with NDK r10d (and probably earlier versions of NDK r10 too)

Answer (score 2):

**Short version**:

replace `expr --` with `expr` in file `$NDK_HOME/build/tools/prebuilt-common.sh` with text editor of your choice. Then run as documented.

**Long version**:

The syntax errors you see in the output coming from android ndk implementation of argument parser. People who wrote this script decided to use `expr` command with regular expressions to parse arguments instead of using `echo $1 | grep ...`. It certainly looks much cleaner (even though echo-grep used in other script from ndk), but `expr` is not the most standart command. It has a set of arguments common to all implementations as detailed in POSIX specification and everything else could be implemented differently or not implemented at all.

If you look inside file `$NDK_HOME/build/tools/prebuilt-common.sh` at line 392 (could depend on NDK version) you code like this:

```
param=`expr -- "$1" : '^\([^\-].*\)$'`
```

Notice how arguments of `expr` are separated by `--`. This is **not** specified in POSIX [specification of `expr`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/expr.html). It's not even mentioned in any [Linux man](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expr). It just works because some host systems have `expr` command that recognizes `--` as "stop parsing arguments". So this is clearly a case of using an **undocumented functionality**.

You seem to use Git-bash - version of bash that comes with mingw32-git an distributed by git-scm.org. This version does not support `expr --` syntax to the whole argument parsing library breaks. In order to fix it - just replace all `expr --` with `expr` in prebuilt-common.sh file. It will still throw some warnings at you, but the script should work.

Comment: This trick worked for me. I'm using git-bash in windows 7 machine. The following command worked for me :  `make-standalone-toolchain.sh --platform=android-19 --arch=arm --install-dir=/root/iqbal/toolchain --ndk-dir=../../ --system=windows-x86_64`

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to cross compilation of library which are written in C we require NDK. But Compiling such type of Library on windows is very difficult and sometimes stuck and its always frustrating. I advise you to try the compilation on Linux. It will definitely be compiled. Linux/Mac are the best platforms for cross compilation. I hope it should help