# Building Standalone Toolchain for NDK 8 on Windows 7

Tags: android, android-ndk, mips, toolchain

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to build android standalone toolchain in windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10527952/how-to-build-android-standalone-toolchain-in-windows-7)

I am trying to build standalone toolchain using ndk 8 for mips by following "docs\STANDALONE-TOOLCHAIN.html" but when I run following command

```
make-standalone-toolchain.sh --platform=android-14 --install-dir=/tmp/my-android-toolchain
```

in command prompt I got errors such as command not found etc. Error details are following:

```
./../core/ndk-common.sh: line 21: basename: command not found
./../core/ndk-common.sh: line 324: expr: command not found
./dev-defaults.sh: line 34: head: command not found
./prebuilt-common.sh: line 186: expr: command not found
./prebuilt-common.sh: line 187: expr: command not found
./prebuilt-common.sh: line 159: name: No such file or directory
./prebuilt-common.sh: line 159: OPTIONS_abstract_Specify: command not found
./prebuilt-common.sh: line 186: expr: command not found
./prebuilt-common.sh: line 187: expr: command not found
./prebuilt-common.sh: line 159: name: No such file or directory
./prebuilt-common.sh: line 159: OPTIONS_abstract_Specify: command not found
./prebuilt-common.sh: line 186: expr: command not found
./prebuilt-common.sh: line 187: expr: command not found
./prebuilt-common.sh: line 159: path: No such file or directory
./prebuilt-common.sh: line 159: path: No such file or directory
./prebuilt-common.sh: line 159: OPTIONS_default_.=: command not found
./prebuilt-common.sh: line 186: expr: command not found
./prebuilt-common.sh: line 187: expr: command not found
./prebuilt-common.sh: line 159: name: No such file or directory
./prebuilt-common.sh: line 159: OPTIONS_abstract_Specify: command not found
./prebuilt-common.sh: line 159: OPTIONS_default_Workstation: command not found
./prebuilt-common.sh: line 186: expr: command not found
./prebuilt-common.sh: line 187: expr: command not found
./prebuilt-common.sh: line 159: path: No such file or directory
./prebuilt-common.sh: line 159: path: No such file or directory
./prebuilt-common.sh: line 159: OPTIONS_default_/tmp/ndk-=: No such file or dire
ctory
./prebuilt-common.sh: line 186: expr: command not found
./prebuilt-common.sh: line 187: expr: command not found
./prebuilt-common.sh: line 159: path: No such file or directory
./prebuilt-common.sh: eval: line 159: unexpected EOF while looking for matching
`''
./prebuilt-common.sh: eval: line 160: syntax error: unexpected end of file
./prebuilt-common.sh: line 186: expr: command not found
./prebuilt-common.sh: line 187: expr: command not found
./prebuilt-common.sh: line 159: name: No such file or directory
./prebuilt-common.sh: line 159: OPTIONS_abstract_Specify: command not found
./prebuilt-common.sh: line 159: OPTIONS_default_android-3=: command not found
./prebuilt-common.sh: line 341: expr: command not found
./prebuilt-common.sh: line 354: expr: command not found
./prebuilt-common.sh: line 362: expr: command not found
./prebuilt-common.sh: line 370: expr: command not found
./prebuilt-common.sh: line 378: expr: command not found
```

Comment: Which command not found? What exactly does error say?

Comment: Do you run it in Cygwin? It doesn't find unix binaries such as basename/expr...

Comment: See the working (but somewhat awkward) [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24978903/192373) in the [linked Q](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10527952/how-to-build-android-standalone-toolchain-in-windows-7).

Answer (score 0):

Please install either cygwin (http://cygwin.com/) or MinGW (http://mingw.org/) including the MSYS system. Ensure that expr.exe is present in the **bin** directory of cygwin/MSYS. If not, install the corresponding package using cygwin/MinGW setup.

Then run the configure script from the Cygwin/MinGW shell.