# Cross-compiling Freetype 2.5.3 for Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, cross-compiling, freetype2

I'm trying to cross-compile Freetype 2.5.3, so I could use it with my Android NDK Opengl ES 2 project, but I'm not sure how to do it. I'm using Cygwin on Windows. I already searched and read a lot of stuff about it, but I still need help.

I exported some flags in cygwin:

```
$ export NDK_TOOLCHAIN=/cygdrive/d/Development/Android/ndk-standalone-15
$ export PATH="$NDK_TOOLCHAIN/bin/:$PATH"
$ export HOST=arm-linux-androideabi
$ export CC=$HOST-gcc
$ export CXX=$HOST-g++
$ export AR=$HOST-ar
$ export LD=$HOST-ld
$ export AS=$HOST-as
$ export NM=$HOST-nm
$ export STRIP=$HOST-strip
$ export RANLIB=$HOST-ranlib
$ export OBJDUMP=$HOST-objdump
$ export CPPFLAGS="--sysroot=$NDK_TOOLCHAIN/sysroot -I$NDK_TOOLCHAIN/sysroot/usr/include -I$NDK_TOOLCHAIN/include"
$ export LDFLAGS="-L$NDK_TOOLCHAIN/sysroot/usr/lib -L$NDK_TOOLCHAIN/lib"
```

And then I tried to cross-compile freetype:

```
$ ./configure --with-sysroot=/cygdrive/d/Development/Android/ndk-standalone-15/sysroot --host=$HOST --prefix=/ft2tmp --build=$BUILD --without-zlib --with-png=no
```

But I got an error:

> FreeType build system -- automatic system detection
>
> The following settings are used:
>
> platform                    unix   compiler
>   arm-linux-androideabi-gcc   configuration directory     ./builds/unix 
>   configuration rules         ./builds/unix/unix.mk
>
> If this does not correspond to your system or settings please remove
>   the file `config.mk' from this directory then read the INSTALL file
>   for help.
>
> Otherwise, simply type `make' again to build the library, or`make
>   refdoc' to build the API reference (the latter needs python).
>
> cd builds/unix; /bin/sh ./configure 
>   '--with-sysroot=/cygdrive/d/Development/Android/ndk-standalone-15/sysroot'
>   '--host=arm-linux-androideabi' '--prefix=/ft2tmp' '--build='
>   '--without-zlib' '--with-png=no' checking build system type...
>   x86_64-unknown-cygwin checking host system type...
>   arm-unknown-linux-androideabi checking for
>   arm-linux-androideabi-gcc... arm-linux-androideabi-gcc checking
>   whether the C compiler works... no configure: error: in
>   `/cygdrive/d/Development/tmp/freetype2/builds/unix': configure: error:
>   C compiler cannot create executables 
>   See`config.log' for more details
>   builds/unix/detect.mk:86: recipe for target 'setup' failed make: ***
>   [setup] Error 77

Some of the config.log file:

> gcc version 4.8 (GCC)  configure:2925: $? = 0 configure:2914:
>   arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -V >&5 arm-linux-androideabi-gcc.exe: error:
>   unrecognized command line option '-V' arm-linux-androideabi-gcc.exe:
>   fatal error: no input files compilation terminated. configure:2925: $?
>   = 1 configure:2914: arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -qversion >&5 arm-linux-androideabi-gcc.exe: error: unrecognized command line option
>   '-qversion' arm-linux-androideabi-gcc.exe: fatal error: no input files
>   compilation terminated. configure:2925: $? = 1 configure:2945:
>   checking whether the C compiler works configure:2967:
>   arm-linux-androideabi-gcc 
>   --sysroot=/cygdrive/d/Development/Android/ndk-standalone-15//sysroot -I/cygdrive/d/Development/Android/ndk-standalone-15//sysroot/usr/include
>   -I/cygdrive/d/Development/Android/ndk-standalone-15//include -L/cygdrive/d/Development/Android/ndk-standalone-15//sysroot/usr/lib -L/cygdrive/d/Development/Android/ndk-standalone-15//lib conftest.c  >&5 d:/development/android/ndk-standalone-15/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe:
>   error: cannot open crtbegin_dynamic.o: No such file or directory
>   d:/development/android/ndk-standalone-15/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe:
>   error: cannot open crtend_android.o: No such file or directory
>   d:/development/android/ndk-standalone-15/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe:
>   error: cannot find -lc
>   d:/development/android/ndk-standalone-15/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe:
>   error: cannot find -ldl collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>   configure:2971: $? = 1 configure:3009: result: no configure: failed

So my question is how should I do this properly?

**EDIT:**

I used unset on CPPFLAGS and LDFLAGS and used ./configure with --with-sysroot flag, and now it's doing okay.
Next problem is that when I use

```
make
```

I get the following error:

> $ make ./builds/unix/libtool --mode=compile arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
>   -pedantic -ansi  -I/cygdrive/d/Development/tmp/freetype2/objs -I./builds/unix -I/cygdrive/d/Development/tmp/freetype2/include -c -Wall -g -O2  -DFT_CONFIG_OPTION_SYSTEM_ZLIB -DFT_CONFIG_CONFIG_H="" -DFT2_BUILD_LIBRARY -DFT_CONFIG_MODULES_H=""  -o /cygdrive/d/Development/tmp/freetype2/objs/ftsystem.lo
>   /cygdrive/d/Development/tmp/freetype2/src/base/ftsystem.c libtool:
>   compile:  arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -pedantic -ansi
>   -I/cygdrive/d/Development/tmp/freetype2/objs -I./builds/unix -I/cygdrive/d/Development/tmp/freetype2/include -c -Wall -g -O2 -DFT_CONFIG_OPTION_SYSTEM_ZLIB "-DFT_CONFIG_CONFIG_H=" -DFT2_BUILD_LIBRARY "-DFT_CONFIG_MODULES_H=" /cygdrive/d/Development/tmp/freetype2/src/base/ftsystem.c  -fPIC -DPIC
>   -o /cygdrive/d/Development/tmp/freetype2/objs/.libs/ftsystem.o arm-linux-androideabi-gcc.exe: error:
>   /cygdrive/d/Development/tmp/freetype2/src/base/ftsystem.c: No such
>   file or directory arm-linux-androideabi-gcc.exe: fatal error: no input
>   files compilation terminated.
>   /cygdrive/d/Development/tmp/freetype2/builds/freetype.mk:207: recipe
>   for target '/cygdrive/d/Development/tmp/freetype2/objs/ftsystem.lo'
>   failed make: ***
>   [/cygdrive/d/Development/tmp/freetype2/objs/ftsystem.lo] Error 1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to set the Windows-style path providing where freetype2 is located. Here is how to include in your windows environment path the libraries and files that you are using for your development in [Android](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/HOWTO_Specify_the_Location_of_Libraries_for_use_with_MinGW). The same thing you need to do for the [freetype2](http://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/tutorial/step1.html).

You may find useful to check these references:

- [Android NDK Cross-Compile Setup (libpng and freetype)](http://mortoray.com/2012/08/21/android-ndk-cross-compile-setup-libpng-and-freetype/)
- [OpenGL Programming/Installation/Android NDK](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Installation/Android_NDK)
- [Setting up Native OpenGL ES* on Android* Platforms](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/setting-up-native-opengl-es-on-android-platforms)
- [Calling OpenGL from C on Android, Using the NDK](http://www.learnopengles.com/calling-opengl-from-android-using-the-ndk/)

As you will probably observe, most of the best [material](http://malideveloper.arm.com/downloads/deved/tutorial/SDK/linux/2.4/tutorials.html) available to develop Android Apps are on Linux:

[image]

In case you are really serious about Android development, it would be worth to consider moving your development to a Linux platform.

You should also have a look on the *[OpenGL Getting Started](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Getting_Started)*, that provides several tutorials on how work with OpenGL on [Linux](http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/instructions.html), Windows and MacOS. Taking a gentle [step by step](http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk) approach is more productive to successfully grow your OpenGL development skills.

Comment: Sorry for the late response! The problem was with the paths indeed, and I managed to cross-compile it on Linux with success. Thanks for the links, I find some of it on my own, and I'll check out the rest too!

Answer (score 3):

When it comes to cross compilation of library which are written in C we require NDK. But Compiling such type of Library on windows is very difficult and sometimes stuck. I advise you to try the compilation on Linux. It will definitely be compiled

Answer (score 1):

NDK for Windows does not depend on Cygwin, and worse: it does not recognize `/cygdrive/...` paths. Try to use `D:/Development/tmp/freetype2`.

Answer (score 0):

First, prepare a standalone NDK toolchain. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/24978903/192373. I used the following parameters:

```
bash-3.1$ d:/dev/Android/ndk/build/tools/make-standalone-toolchain.sh --platform=android-14 --toolchain=arm-linux-androideabi-4.8 --system=windows-x86_64 --arch=armv7a
```

Next, make sure that you have working `/usr/bin/gcc`.

```
bash-3.1$ ./configure --host=arm-linux-androideabi --prefix=d:/Dev/Android/standalone-toolchain-armv7a-android-17 --without-zlib --with-png=no
```

Finally, I run `make` and I see

```
 Directory of d:\dev\freetype-2.5.3\objs\.libs

27/07/2014  10:43         3,462,596 libfreetype.a
27/07/2014  10:43               960 libfreetype.la
27/07/2014  10:43               961 libfreetype.lai
27/07/2014  10:43         2,320,272 libfreetype.so
```